# Custom NSManagedObject subclass constructor

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have a question about CoreData and NSManagedObject.

In the architecture of my application I have a REST client That builds instances of objects That I receive from the server.

For example I have this method:

```
- (NSArray*) getAllCards:(NSDictionary*) jsonResponse;
```

That takes the JSON response and returns an array of Cards.

It's ok ...

Now I need to save my Card in CoreData.

I defined my model so I have some subclass of NSManagedObject. 
For example: `Card: NSManagedObject`

but I would like to have a simple constructor to construct the object from the JSON and then pass this to my manager who will add it in CoreData.

I would not pass some info related to CoreData (eg. Context ..) to my Client REST ... I would like to have the logic in my CoreData CoreData Manager ..

How can I define a valid constructor of my Cards?

Can I define a constructor in this way?

```
- (id) initWithName:(NSString*) name
             cardId:(NSString*) cardId
         type:(NSString*) type
{
    self = [super initWithEntity:nil insertIntoManagedObjectContext:nil]; //This is wrong..
    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
        self.cardId = cardId;
        self.type = type;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no need to override the init methods. Just give your `CoreDataManager` class a method that takes the dictionary and generates the core data entities.

```
-(void)storeCardsFromJSON:(NSDictionary*)dictionary {
   for (NSDictionary *cardInfo in dictionary[@"cardArray"]) {
       Card *newCard = [NSEntityDescription insert...];
       newCard.cardID = cardInfo[@"cardID"];
       // etc.
   }
   // save
}
```

Optionally, return an array of newly created cards. In this method you could also filter out the cards that already exist (e.g. based on the `cardID` attribute) and modify those instead of inserting them again.

In your app, you should only use the `Card` objects from Core Data. There is no need to have a different class of objects, or use `NSDictionary` objects.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help: for all of my NSManagedObject subclasses, that can be created from JSON, I added a category with names like MyObject+JSON and I have 2 methods there:

```
+ (instancetype)deserializeFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
- (void)updateFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary;
```

I use inContext: part because I usually insert objects in batches using private context for the whole transaction.

Methods look like this:

```
+ (instancetype)deserializeFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context;
{
    if (!dictionary || ![dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || !context) {
        return nil;
    }

    MyObject *anObject = (MyObject *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"MyObject" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [anObject updateFromDictionary:dictionary];

    return anObject;
}
```

And

```
- (void)updateFromDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary
{
    NSParameterAssert(dictionary);
    if (!dictionary || ![dictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
        return;
    }

    self.identifier = dictionary[@"id"];
    self.title      = dictionary[@"title"]; //and so on     
}
```